# How to draw svg coordinate space where x=0 and y=0 coordinates fall on the bottom left

Tags: d3.js, svg

Hi basically svg coordinate space growing from top to bottom.what should i change to growing from bottom to top as like Graph Coordinate Space. the below code which draws top to bottom in left side how i need change to bottom to top

```
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500);

//Create and append line
svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 100)
        .attr("x2", 500)
        .attr("y1", 50)
        .attr("y2", 250)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a simple transform to the main SVG element to flip the coordinates:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", 500)
              .attr("height", 500)
              .attr( 'transform', 'scale( 1 -1 )' );
```

[MDN @ `scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Transformations#Scaling)

Comment: If there's any text it will now be upside down.

Comment: In OPs question there was just some geometry and no text ,-) Anyways another `scale()` call on the text elements should fix that problem.

Comment: @PradeepGowda What should I see in that fiddle? The line appears to be just as you asked.

Comment: i am not getting a line after added transform

Comment: @PradeepGowda What browser are you using? The line displays just fine for me (FF56).

Comment: chrome but am not getting in any browser

Comment: sorry, in chrome its working, why can't in jsfiddle,firefox even IE

Comment: IE shows the line for me, but ignores the transform. I guess they lack the SVG support in that area. As for FF - i have no clue. I almost never had any problems regarding SVG in FF.